# CVE-2012-5785 fix in apache axis2

Tags: security, software-update, vulnerabilities

Can anyone please tell me in which version of Apache axis2 CVE-2012-5785 is fixed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please tell me in which version of Apache axis2 CVE-2012-5785 is fixed?

Directly from the vulnerability description

> Apache Axis2/Java 1.6.2 and earlier does not verify that the server hostname matches a domain name in the subject's Common Name (CN) or subjectAltName field of the X.509 certificate, which allows man-in-the-middle attackers to spoof SSL servers via an arbitrary valid certificate.

[Source](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2012-5785?cpeVersion=2.2#vulnConfigurationsArea)

I should point out no release after **1.6.2** specifically indicates they fixed that particular vulnerability.  However, you should be using the current version, **1.7.7** to have the best chance of not being vulnerable due to numerous changes since 2012.  Without a proof of concept code it will be difficult to prove the current version is still vulnerable. It’s literally the fix was documented as something else and simply didn’t call out this particular CVE in the change log